# How is 'users'=>array('admin') set in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have a function in my `WebUser` `getIsAdmin`

```
public function getIsAdmin() {
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    if ($user === null) {
        return false;
    }
    return intval($user->user_level_id) == AccountModule::USER_LEVEL_ADMIN;
}
```

Yet my rule in my controller isn't working

```
array('allow',
      'actions'=>array('index','create','upload'),
      'users'=>array('admin'),
),
```

Where do I set so the user is an `admin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `users` property in an access control filter just check for the user name only, ie it checks for `Yii::app()->user->name=='admin'`. In your scenario you can use the `expression` property. The access is granted only if the expression evaluated to true. The `$user` variable can be used in an expression as an alias for `Yii::app()->user`. So your condition would be

```
array('allow',
      'actions'=>array('index','create','upload'),
      'expression'=>'$user->getIsAdmin()',
),
```